# Load ActiveDirectory PowerShell Module in Runspace without AD Drive Letter

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to load the ActiveDirectory module inside a custom SnapIn that I'm working on. However, when I do so I get the annoying error

> "Error initializing default drive: 'Unable to find a default server
>   with Active Directory Web Services running.'"

which takes a good 15 seconds or so to timeout. From within a normal PowerShell console I realize you can set a variable to disable the AD: drive mapping but, I cannot seem to get that working from within C# code.

```
InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
initial.Variables.Add(new SessionStateVariableEntry("ADPS_LoadDefaultDrive",
                                                    0, 
                                                    string.Empty));
initial.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "ActiveDirectory" });

using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial))
        {
            runspace.Open();
            using (Pipeline p = runspace.CreatePipeline())
            {
                Command getGroup = new Command("Get-ADGroup");
                getGroup.Parameters.Add("Filter", this.Group);
                p.Commands.Add(getGroup);

                var results = p.Invoke();
                this.WriteObject(results, true);
            }
        }
```

I've included what I think should work but, the ADPS_LoadDefaultDrive setting seems to be ignored as each time I try to make a call into the ActiveDirectory module I get the same web services error (along with a painful timeout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `ADPS_LoadDefaultDrive` as an Environment variable, not a regular session variable.

Comment: That did it. I kept thinking that I should be setting an environment variable somehow within the PowerShell runspace and not within the overall "environment"

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ADPS_LoadDefaultDrive", "0");

Comment: and how I can do it on Windows Server 2008r2? On my Client it works but on 2008r2 on II7 it say me that I don't have the rights :(

Comment: Not sure I follow you, ADPS_LoadDefaultDrive is related to the AD module, not IIS. Anyway, try to open PowerShell as an administrator.